# python 2.7 cx_Oracle raises many ORA-XXXXX exceptions while executing a simple query

Tags: python-2.7, oracle11g, cx-oracle

While executing simple SQL queries, cx_Oracle (5.1.3) throws some random exceptions intermittently.

```
def execute_query(name, asize=100, mapper=default_mapper, **kwargs):
    with session_pool.acquire() as conn:
        sql = read_sql(name)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.arraysize = asize
        cursor.prepare(sql, name)
        cursor.execute(None, kwargs)
        return mapper(cursor)
```

`read_sql(name)` simply reads query string from a file, while session_pool is a `cx_Oracle.SessionPool` object with plenty of idle connections. `mapper` is a row mapper function that returns a `list` of `dict`.

Most of calls will return no rows, but occasionally it throws randomly

```
ORA-03106: fatal two-task communication protocol error
ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation
```

Also, the query sometimes just blocks for over a minute before continuing. It is a static query with a single table with one bind variable, can't get any simpler than that. Also, there is only a single thread executing this. Anyone with even remotely similar experience?

Comment: Is the database remote? And if so, is your network stable? The last error is a result of a break being executed -- usually by hitting Ctrl-C. Also, there is no need to run cursor.prepare() followed by cursor.execute(). The prepare call is not needed.

Comment: It is remote. I was suspicious of some network issue, as these unpredictable errors are sign of corrupted stream. But it is a common pattern with what we do all the time.
So the driver cache the parsed SQL automatically? I was wondering about that as well.

Comment: Yes, the driver prepares the statement automatically when you execute a statement and if you execute the same statement on the same cursor the prepare step is skipped.